# Как лучше перевести слово Badges?

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, знаки

А хорошо ли **Знаки** (в оригинале **Badges**) называть **Знаками**?

Может быть лучше назвать их **Значками**?

Answer (score 1):

Мы обсуждали этот вопрос в [контексте терминов перевода](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/research/3048/). Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на [само обсуждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3195/).

Comment: Очень интересное обсуждение! Вариант "Знак" набрал меньше всего голосов. К этой теме еще можно вернуться или это окончательный вариант?

Comment: И еще вопрос -- где можно прочитать про взаимоотношения stackexchange с hashcode?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Сделал так, как должно быть. Спасибо за замечание.

Comment: спасибо за оперативную реакцию. Кстати, а пользователь получит уведомления о комментариях или новых ответах, если он еще не зарегистрирован на этом сайте?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Точно сказать не берусь (уточню завтра), но кажется, что нет.

Comment: хотя бы о переносе вопроса бы уведомить, дальше сможет зарегистрироваться.

Answer (score 0):

Значки, конечно. Знак тоже возможно, но тут сильно путает непосвященных. А впрочем, все фигня, кроме пчел. Как не назови, только в печку не ставь.

Comment: Это будет кто-то чинить? Здесь есть пасечник?