# Как я могу посмотреть все вопросы, которые я отметил звездой?

Tags: поддержка, избранное

Находясь на этом сайте, я помечал некоторые интересные мне вопросы звездочками (слева, где +-).

Перерыл вроде бы все у себя в профиле, но найти не выходит. Как я могу теперь найти все вопросы, которые я таким образом отметил?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В своём профиле в любой учётке кликнуть ссылку "Профиль сети" (Network profile). Откроется профиль StackExchange. Там на вкладке favorites будут все отмеченные звездой вопросы, во всех учётках.

Answer (score 14):

В профиле, верхняя вкладка **Активность**, нижняя вкладка **[Избранное](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=favorites)**.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На звёздочке подсказка *"Нажмите, чтобы добавить в **избранное**"*, что мягко намекает.

Comment: Интересно. То есть, например находясь на русском stackoverflow я вижу там только те вопросы, которые относятся к русскому stackoverflow?

Comment: @Andrew разумеется, ведь профили на каждом сайте свои, хоть и могут быть связаны.

Comment: Не подскажете как их все связать между собой?

Comment: @Andrew Ну, у вас уже есть связанные профили SO, ruSO и AU. Вы ещё что-то хотите привязать?

Comment: Я бы хотел чтоб все закладки были доступны из одного места :)

Comment: @Andrew Тогда лучше использовать механизм синхронизируемых браузерных закладок :Р

Answer (score 11):

Если в списке избранного много вопросов, можно найти нужный по ключевым словам с параметром [infavorites:mine](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3Amine), например "bash script infavorites:mine".

Если никак не находится, возможно, что вопрос был удалён.